# Php unsupported operand type

Tags: php, date, time, operand

I got this:

```
$newcw = array_rand( range( 1, 52 ), 15 ) ;
shuffle($newcw);
$year = date("Y");
$time = mktime(0,0,0,1,1,$year) + ($newcw * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60);
$time = $time - ((date('N', $time) - 1) * 24 * 60 * 60);

$startWeek = date('D d-M-Y', $time);
$endWeek = date('D d-M-Y', $time + (6 * 24 * 60 * 60));
```

So basically I get a random integer which stands for calender week.

I calculate the starting day (monday) and ending day(sunday)
of that calender week.

But I get following error:

> Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in 88

line 88 would be this line:

```
$time = mktime(0,0,0,1,1,$year) + ($newcw * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60);
```

EDIT:
I want a random integer which shall not repeats itself, that it why I am trying this method.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want a single value, use regular `rand` function:

```
//$newcw = array_rand( range( 1, 52 ), 15 ) ;
//shuffle($newcw);

$newcw = rand(1,52);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

If however you actually need to use the other 14 values somewhere later in the script, you can just select the 1st element in the suffled array for this calculation:

```
$newcw = array_rand( range( 1, 52 ), 15 ) ;
shuffle($newcw);
$year = date("Y");
$time = mktime(0,0,0,1,1,$year) + ($newcw[0] * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60); //<-- note [0]
```

Then use the other values as required, by incrementing the key each time, eg:

```
some_func($newcw[1]); 

$val = $newcs[2] + 100; 
//....
another_func($newcw[14];
```

Comment: The thing is I want a random integer which shall not repeats itself, that it why I am trying this method

Comment: @JonDon Please explain - do you mean you need all 15 values in this script? If yes then just access each one by key as i demonstrate in the second paragraph. so the next value would be `$newcw[1]`

Comment: Can I access all keys at once?

Comment: @JonDon Well `$newcw` is an array, so it already contains all 15 values. If you want to use one after the other, just increment the key each time: `some_func($newcw[0]); $val = $newcs[1] + 100; another_func($newcw[2];` etc

Comment: Thanks could you write this in your answer so its formatted

Comment: @JonDon, if the answer solved your problem, you might consider accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

`$newcw` is array and you try to mutiply array with integer that is why you get error in this line

Comment: use rand() with modulo operator which suits more there you can also get variable from $newcw with `$newcw[rand() % count($newcw) - 1]`